# How can I use xmltodict to get items out of an XML file?

Tags: python, xml, xmltodict

I am trying to easily access values from an XML file like this:

```
<artikelen>
    <artikel nummer="121">
        <code>ABC123</code>
        <naam>Highlight pen</naam>
        <voorraad>231</voorraad>
        <prijs>0.56</prijs>
    </artikel>
    <artikel nummer="123">
        <code>PQR678</code>
        <naam>Nietmachine</naam>
        <voorraad>587</voorraad>
        <prijs>9.99</prijs>
    </artikel>
..... etc
```

How would I go about getting access to the value `ABC123`?

```
import xmltodict

with open('8_1.html') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
    print(doc[fd]['code'])
```

Answer (score 36):

Using your example:

```
import xmltodict

with open('artikelen.xml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
```

If you examine `doc`, you'll see it's an `OrderedDict`, ordered by tag:

```
>>> doc
OrderedDict([('artikelen',
              OrderedDict([('artikel',
                            [OrderedDict([('@nummer', '121'),
                                          ('code', 'ABC123'),
                                          ('naam', 'Highlight pen'),
                                          ('voorraad', '231'),
                                          ('prijs', '0.56')]),
                             OrderedDict([('@nummer', '123'),
                                          ('code', 'PQR678'),
                                          ('naam', 'Nietmachine'),
                                          ('voorraad', '587'),
                                          ('prijs', '9.99')])])]))])
```

The root node is called `artikelen`, and there is a subnode `artikel` which is a list of `OrderedDict` objects, so if you want the `code` for every article, you would do:

```
codes = []
for artikel in doc['artikelen']['artikel']:
    codes.append(artikel['code'])

# >>> codes
# ['ABC123', 'PQR678']
```

If you specifically want the `code` only when `nummer` is `121`, you could do this:

```
code = None
for artikel in doc['artikelen']['artikel']:
    if artikel['@nummer'] == '121':
        code = artikel['code']
        break
```

That said, if you're parsing XML documents and want to search for a specific value like that, I would consider using [XPath expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath), which are supported by `ElementTree`.

Answer (score -1):

This is using xml.etree
You can try this:

```
for artikelobj in root.findall('artikel'):
    print artikelobj.find('code')
```

if you want to extract a specific code based on the attribute 'nummer' of artikel, then you can try this:

```
for artikelobj in root.findall('artikel'):
    if artikel.get('nummer') == 121:
        print artikelobj.find('code')
```

this will print only the code you want.

Answer (score -2):

You can use lxml package using XPath Expression.

```
from lxml import etree
f = open("8_1.html", "r")
tree = etree.parse(f)
expression = "/artikelen/artikel[1]/code"
l = tree.xpath(expression)
code = next(i.text for i in l)
print code

# ABC123
```

The thing to notice here is the expression. `/artikelen` is the root element. `/artikel[1]` chooses the first `artikel` element under `root`(Notice first element is not at index 0). `/code` is the child element under `artikel[1]`. You can read more about at [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#using-xpath-to-find-text) and [xpath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

Answer (score -3):

To read .xml files :

```
import lxml.etree as ET
root = ET.parse(filename).getroot()
value = root.node1.node2.variable_name.text
```

Comment: In your example :
`result = root.artikel.code.text`

Comment: the import is not correct because python gives an error

Comment: What's the error message ? Did you install lxml package ?