# how to extract xml data from CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file format: id ,name..., one of his rows contain an XML file like this

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><session><appUsage packageName=""com.facebook.katana"" name=""Facebook"" startTime=""1603137470472""><state name=""[]"" className=""android.widget.FrameLayout"" duration=""1639"" interactionCount=""0"" orientation=""1""/><state name=""[Facebook]""
```

I am trying to extract the packageName and statTime.Howa can i do ? Please help

Comment: try using,[`xmltodict`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40157811/4985099) to convert xml to dict then use [`csv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10373268/4985099) module to dump to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XML parser and extract the data you are looking for.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
               <session>
                   <appUsage packageName="com.facebook.katana" name="Facebook" startTime="1603137470472">
                        <state name="[]" className="android.widget.FrameLayout" duration="1639" interactionCount="0" orientation="1"/>
                        <state name="[Facebook]"/>
                    </appUsage>
               </session>
'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
package_name = root.find('.//appUsage').attrib['packageName']
print(package_name)
```

output

```
com.facebook.katana
```

Comment: the above code will help if you have separate string. but are you able to read csv that contains xml string and able to create proper data frame