# Converting an xml to dictionary

Tags: python, xmltodict

I have an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
  <item type="dict">
    <job_id type="str">id-1</job_id >
    <title type="str">title-1</title>
    <desc type="str">desc-1</desc>
  </item>
  <item type="dict">
    <job_id type="str">id-2</job_id>
    <title type="str">title-2</title>
    <desc type="str">desc-2</desc>
  </item>
</items>
```

I want to parse this into a dictionary, in such a way that I can access the job using it's id. So the dictionary key will be `job_id` and the whole job definition will the corresponding value.

Here is what I have tried:

```py
class Job:
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = "path-to-xml-file"
        self.job_dict = {}

    def load_jobs(self, env, path):
        file = read_from_s3(env, full_path) # reads the job file from S3 bucket
        dict = xmltodict.parse(file)

        for item in dict['items']['item']:
            key = item['job_id']
            self.job_dict[key] = item # <-- I get exception on this line
```

I get the following exception when I try to add element to the dictionary:

> [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'TypeError'>: unhashable type:
> 'collections.OrderedDict'

Also in the watch window, this is what I see for `item`:

[image]

and this is what I see for `key`:

[image]

Comment: You should debug/print the return value from xmltodict.parse then you'll see that the dictionary structure is not what you thought it would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item['job_id']` is a dict. You cant use that as a key in your `self.job_dict = {}`.

Change it to `key = item['job_id']['#text']` instead

---

Just to better understand the error, the object implementing a dictionary key must implement magic method `__hash__()`.
This means a key must be hashable for the dictionary structure to be optimized.

Comment: Thanks... I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154727/how-to-use-xmltodict-to-get-items-out-of-an-xml-file/40157811#40157811) answer... I am confused if I am missing something? Because according to that answer I wouldn't need `[#text]`?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini xml in the mentioned question does not contain additional attributes like `type` in your case. Thats why xmttodict adds an additional layer for you to accommodate type. Print your parsed dict, you will understand the complete structure.

Comment: Your answer solves the problem though... just not sure if there is a better approach?